# UIImageView added as a subview of a tab is allowing selection of controls under it

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller

At my app starts, the first tab is selected, it consists of a `UITableView` displaying some infos, but before displaying the `UITableView`, the tab is displaying a `UIImageView` from within its `viewDidLoad` method:

**viewDidLoad:**

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"];
    splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    splashImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 410);
[((UITabBarController*)self.parentViewController.parentViewController).view addSubview:splashImageView];
```

The problem is that when I click on the `splashImageView`, the touch is firing the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method of the `UITableView` although its under the `splashImageView`, so why do I get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `splashImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`
also, try setting `splashImageView.opaque = YES;`

Comment: you right, we must explicitly set `userInteractionEnabled` property to yes for `UIImageView`, here is the relevant apple documentation: New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, Just try :)

It is because of UIImageView is completely transparent to touch events. Better u create a view   and use a UIImageView on it.Initially it disregard user events by default, try setting userInteractionEnabled